# ORACLE SQL: Inserting another ID from another row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have write a series of SQL statements in an ORACLE database. In my database, I have 2 tables (book, publisher).

Below is the table structure

```
BOOK
----------
bk_id | title | pub_id

PUBLISHER
----------
pub_id | pub_name
```

If I insert into the publisher table first

```
INSERT INTO PUBLISHER (pub_name) VALUE ('ABC Publisher');
```

How do I retrieve the id of the publisher and enter it into the book table?

I usually do this with a stored procedure (SQL Server) or do it in the application.

How can I do it in ORACLE in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PL/SQL, you might want to use the [`RETURNING INTO`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) clause to get back the newly inserted id:

```
DECLARE
    my_id int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PUBLISHER (pub_name) VALUE ('ABC Publisher')
      RETURNING id INTO my_id;
    ...
END;
```

where `my_id` is a PL/SQL variable declared accordingly to your column type.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would consist in creating a `Trigger` that would insert in other `table` after table.

```
create or replace trigger tr_ai_publisher
after insert on publisher
for each row
begin
   --Here you can access the new publisher id using :new.pub_id
end;
```

That way, you would not have to handle yourself a call to the procedure.

However, if you really want to, you can also use a stored procedure in `ORACLE`, the general syntax is

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE proc_name [list of parameters] 
IS    
   Declaration section 
BEGIN    
   Execution section 
EXCEPTION    
  Exception section 
END;
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but using a sub-query you assume that `pub_name` is (and will always be) an unique key. It is not specified like that here. And in the general case, it might be a rather dangerous assumption (think about employee's name : you might easily have duplicate values)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I completly agree, read to fast the question at first, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a select statement:

```
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES
(bk_id, title, (SELECT pub_id FROM PUBLISHER WHERE pub_name = publisher_name))
…
;
```

Replace bk_id, title, and publisher_name with the appropriate data you want.

Comment: I'd imagine, although I never used such; just give it the args needed and let it substitute for you.

Comment: @PeterSun Yes. I used it a lot of times in my PLSQL scripts and stored procedures.